# ElasticSearch Couchbase Replication Issue

Tags: elasticsearch, replication, couchbase

I have a problem with my `ElasticSearch` cluster in `Couchbase`  XDCR configuration.

I put private ip 10.28.0.21 as IP ( my elasticsearch and couchbase in the same server) when creating cluster reference. Then the system change that by public IP (92.222..) of my server. It is very strange. I don't know why?

Couchbase logs show :

> Updated remote cluster 'ElasticSearch' hostname to "92.222..:9091" because old one
>   ("10.28.0.21:9091") is not part of the cluster anymore

Thanks for any suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couchbase uses the IP that ElasticSearch returns as its host address. If you want ElasticSearch to publish the private IP instead of the public, you can override it with the `network.publish_host` setting in elasticsearch.yml. If the private IP isn't static, you might have to set it to the IP of a particular network interface, such as `_eth0_`.  Take a look here for more details: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-network.html